# How unit test logic in xamarin forms with a separated console project with F#?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, f#, visual-studio-mac

I have a complete new/empty project with xamarin.forms 2.3.4 with F#.

I have a shared project, with a extra module for the logic:

```
module Db

let openDb() =
    printf "Hello"
```

Then I create a console project, reference the shared project & related libraries, and try to run it:

```
open Db

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   Db.openDb()
   0
```

Now I getting this error:

```
../Test/Tests.fs(6,6): Error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Db' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   XDB (FS0039) (Test)
```

I not getting any other error. I try both with xamarin & Visual Studio Mac; and also creating a UI test project (however, I only care for logic testing).

This is an empty form project without anything else.

P.D: I make it to work if a just delete the reference to the shared project and link manually the files. However, I wonder if is possible to cover this scenario...

Comment: Can you post a link to your whole codebase?

Answer (score 1):

Is there an EntryPoint file under the file that defines the module?
The location of the file can be changed with `alt` +`up arrow` and `alt` +`down arrow`(win + visual studio) or Db.fs(in Solution Explorer) is `right click` -> `Move up`

F# is readed file from up to down.(See "Projects and Solutions" on this [site](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/installing-and-using/) )

It Maybe that(win10 ,visual studio 2017)

[image]

`Db.fs` is difine module. There is an entry EntryPoint `program.fs`.
Also, if the namespace and the module name are the same, an error will occur. module name for this project is Bar.

Comment: No, the Db.fs is in the shared project. In test is only test files.